# if the curvature is constant and positive, then it is on the circunference

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that if $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is a $C^2$ regular curve $(\alpha'\neq0)$ with constant and positive curvature, then $\alpha$ is on the circumference and if $\alpha$ is on the circumference, then it's curvature is constant.

I solved the second part since $\alpha$ is the circunference, then $\alpha(t)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, so $|\alpha'(t)|=r$, I need help in the first part.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your first sentence is somewhat mangled.

Comment: @MichaelHardy is it ok now?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your question. Do you mean to ask for help with the proof: "$\alpha$ is a plane curve with constant, positive curvature $\kappa$ if and only if $\alpha$ is part of a circle"?

Comment: @AWertheim yes it's exactly what I meant

Comment: Much better now.

Comment: Hint: You can find the center and radius of the circle explicitly. A circle with radius $r$ is parametrized by a curve of constant curvature $1/r$. So the center of the circle should be distance $1/r$ away from the curve. In what direction? Try the principal normal direction (either positive or negative, depending on your sign convention).

Comment: To clarify some confusing notation: if the curvature is $\kappa$, then the center of the circle should be distance $1/\kappa$ from the curve. Sorry about any possible confusion.

Comment: @R_squared IIRC, _its_, the possessive of _it_, has no apostrophe. By contrast, _it's_ is a contraction of _it is_. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my hints, following the argument given by John Oprea in his text "Differential Geometry and Its Applications". If you are still confused, Oprea's text has a complete proof of this problem, but try and see if you can solve it yourself first given these hints.

Suppose, without loss of generality, that $\alpha$ is a unit speed curve.

Suppose $\alpha$ is part of a circle. Then since every point on $\alpha$ is a fixed distance $r$ away from some point $p$, we can write:

$(\alpha(t) - p)\cdot(\alpha(t) - p) = r^{2}$

Differentiate this expression several times with respect to $t$. See if you can't use the expressions you obtain to show that $\kappa \neq 0$, i.e., $\kappa > 0$. Then see if you can't get an expression involving $\frac{d\kappa}{ds}$ and use this expression to conclude $\frac{d\kappa}{ds}$ is 0, i.e., $\kappa$ is constant.

Now suppose $\alpha$ has positive constant curvature. See if you can't show that the curve $\gamma(t) = \alpha(t) + \frac{1}{\kappa}N$ is actually constant, i.e., a point $p$. From here, see if you can't use this to show that $\alpha$ is a fixed distance away from from $p$ using what you know about $N$.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot

Comment: No problem, my pleasure!